# Not able to interact with Ganache-cli: "-bash: ganache-cli: command not found"

Tags: ganache, web3.py, ganache-cli, npm

I've already installed ganache-cli with `sudo npm install -g ganache-cli` on my MacOS but I am not able to interact with it through my terminal.

I always get the error: `-bash: ganache-cli: command not found`.

Maybe it isn't installed on the right PATH?

Would be glad for help. The normal version of Ganache is working properly on my computer, but with that, I cannot fork the blockchain.

Comment: I am having a similar issue, though I installed ganache through:
yarn global add ganache-cli
instead of through npm and on Fedora.  I'm following along through a tutorial, so I'm really surprised the above didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should (almost) never use `sudo` with `npm`. Once you do so the folders and files npm touches/creates are now locked to the root user *only*.

> The simplest solution is to do `sudo rm -rf node_modules` for whatever project you are currently in. Similarly, you may have to do something akin to `sudo rm -rf $(npm prefix -g)/{bin,lib/node_modules}` in case you globally installed node modules with the wrong prefix. Just be aware that *this **will** remove libraries you installed with `sudo` before*, so you will have to install them again. The right way.
>
> More specifically **pay attention to the output**. Read what npm is telling you and find the directory that is causing a problem specifically. Remove it. If you can't remove it, you'll have to use `sudo rm`.
> Ultimately you should be able to do an `npm install` or `npm install -g` without using `sudo`.

(from https://medium.com/@ExplosionPills/dont-use-sudo-with-npm-5711d2726aa3)

Aside: Ganache UI does allow you to use the forking feature:

[image: Ganache UI forking]

Comment: @Royal.Flush, feel free to upvote the answer if you found it helpful.